# Why is printf in F# so slow?

Tags: performance, f#

I've just been really surprised by how slow printf from F# is. I have a number of C# programs that process large data files and write out a number of CSV files. I originally started by using `fprintf writer "%s,%d,%f,%f,%f,%s"` thinking that that would be simple and reasonably efficient.

However after a while I was getting a bit fed up with waiting for the files to process. (I've got 4gb XML files to go through and write out entries from them.).

When I ran my applications through a profiler, I was amazed to see printf as being one of the really slow methods.

I changed the code to not use printf and now performance is so much better. Printf performance was killing my overall application performance.

To give an example, my original code is:

```
fprintf sectorWriter "\"%s\",%f,%f,%d,%d,\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",%d,%d,%d,%d,\"%s\",%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%d"
    sector.Label sector.Longitude sector.Latitude sector.RNCId sector.CellId
    siteName sector.Switch sector.Technology (int sector.Azimuth) sector.PrimaryScramblingCode
    (int sector.FrequencyBand) (int sector.Height) sector.PatternName (int sector.Beamwidth) 
    (int sector.ElectricalTilt) (int sector.MechanicalTilt) (int (sector.ElectricalTilt + sector.MechanicalTilt))
    sector.SectorType (int sector.Radius)
```

And I've changed it to be the following

```
seq {
    yield sector.Label; yield string sector.Longitude; yield string sector.Latitude; yield string sector.RNCId; yield string sector.CellId; 
    yield siteName; yield sector.Switch; yield sector.Technology; yield string (int sector.Azimuth); yield string sector.PrimaryScramblingCode;
    yield string (int sector.FrequencyBand); yield string (int sector.Height); yield sector.PatternName; yield string (int sector.Beamwidth); 
    yield string (int sector.ElectricalTilt); yield string (int sector.MechanicalTilt); 
    yield string (int (sector.ElectricalTilt + sector.MechanicalTilt));
    yield sector.SectorType; yield string (int sector.Radius)
}
|> writeCSV sectorWriter
```

Helper functions

```
let writeDelimited delimiter (writer:TextWriter) (values:seq<string>) =
    values
    |> Seq.fold (fun (s:string) v -> if s.Length = 0 then v else s + delimiter + v) ""
    |> writer.WriteLine

let writeCSV (writer:TextWriter) (values:seq<string>) = writeDelimited "," writer values
```

I'm writing out files with about 30,000 rows. Nothing special.

Comment: printf is a very general facility. That's not for free.

Comment: I understand that, but was staggered at just how slow it was. I think it's because it is recalling the function for each argument (or something like that)

Comment: You may want to have a look at the source code to see what's going on: http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54799#970095

Comment: Slow compared to what exactly? Can you post some code similar to yours that we can use to profile it?

Comment: What did you switch to (you went from printf to...)?

Comment: I've updated the post with some more information to indicate what I am doing

Comment: but you've changed code, and added the sequence expression, so i don't think you are running a clean test to see if printf is really slow...seems you are comparing printf with building a sequence?

Comment: @Alex - looks clean to me: both `fprintf` and `writeCSV` are writing to a `TextWriter`

Comment: @Nick - you can concat your sequence of strings more efficiently using `String.concat` instead of `Seq.fold`

Comment: @Nick : If you're concerned about performance at all, why are you using string concatenation instead of `StringBuilder`?

Comment: I know I can use StringBuilder and other things - though I forgot about String.Concat!. At the time I was trying to solve a problem and wanted a solution quickly (ie impatiently)

Comment: @Peter G: "printf is a very general facility. That's not for free". On the contrary, F# mimics `printf` in OCaml which is *extremely* fast, several times faster than `printf` in C (with gcc).

Comment: @Jon Harrop. Then, Nick Randell has used print the wrong way? Should he have reused a printf with bound format? Do you have other suggestions how to use printf in a way fast enough for Nick Randall's problem?

Comment: @Peter G: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that this can be fast in F#. Although F# mimics the semantics of `printf` in OCaml, where it is very fast, F# does nothing to replicate the optimizations that make OCaml so fast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure how much it matters, but...

Inspecting the code for printf:

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs

I see

```
// The general technique used this file is to interpret
// a format string and use reflection to construct a function value that matches
// the specification of the format string.
```

and I think the word 'reflection' probably answers the question.

`printf` is great for writing simple type-safe output, but if you want good perf in an inner loop, you might want to use a lower-level .NET API to write output.  I haven't done my own benchmarking to see.

Answer (score 10):

`TextWriter` already buffers its output. I recommend using `Write` to output each value, one at a time, instead of formatting an entire line and passing it to `WriteLine`. On my laptop, writing 100,000 lines takes nearly a minute using your function, while, using the following function, it runs in half a second.

```
let writeRow (writer:TextWriter) siteName (sector:Sector) = 
  let inline write (value:'a) (delim:char) = 
    writer.Write(value)
    writer.Write(delim)
  let inline quote s = "\"" + s + "\""
  write (quote sector.Label) ','
  write sector.Longitude ','
  write sector.Latitude ','
  write sector.RNCId ','
  write sector.CellId ','
  write (quote siteName) ','
  write (quote sector.Switch) ','
  write (quote sector.Technology) ','
  write (int sector.Azimuth) ','
  write sector.PrimaryScramblingCode ','
  write (int sector.FrequencyBand) ','
  write (int sector.Height) ','
  write (quote sector.PatternName) ','
  write (int sector.Beamwidth) ','
  write (int sector.ElectricalTilt) ','
  write (int sector.MechanicalTilt) ','
  write (int (sector.ElectricalTilt + sector.MechanicalTilt)) ','
  write sector.SectorType ','
  write (int sector.Radius) '\n'
```

Answer (score 8):

Now that F# 3.1 has been preview released, the performance of `printf` is claimed to have increased by 40x. You might want to have a look at this:

> F# 3.1 Compiler/Library Additions
>
> Printf performance
>
> The F# 3.1 core library sees improved performance of the printf family
>   of functions for type-safe formatting. For example, printing using 
>   the following format string now runs up to **40x** faster (though your
>   exact mileage may vary):
>
> `sprintf "%d: %d, %x %X %d %d %s"` No changes in your code are needed to
>   take advantage of this improved performance, though you do need to be
>   using the F# 3.1 FSharp.Core.dll runtime component.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT: This answer is only valid for simple format strings, like "%s" or "%d". See comments below.**

It is also interesting to note that if you can make a curried function and reuse that, the reflection will only be carried out once. Sample:

```
let w = new System.IO.StringWriter() :> System.IO.TextWriter
let printer = fprintf w "%d"
let printer2 d = fprintf w "%d" d

let print1() = 
   for i = 1 to 100000 do
      printer 2
let print2() = 
   for i = 1 to 100000 do
      printer2 2
let time f = 
   let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
   sw.Start()
   f()
   printfn "%s" (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString())

time print1
time print2
```

print1 takes 48 ms on my machine while print2 takes 1158 ms.

Comment: I up-voted your answer, but now that I've had a chance to test, I'm not seeing any difference with the curried version. I'm using `let writef = fprintf TextWriter.Null "\"%s\",%f,%f,%d,%d,\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",%d,%d,%d,%d,\"%s\",%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%d"`.

Comment: @Daniel - Nice catch! Doing some further testing, it appears you only get the drastic speed-up if there's only one argument. It is enough to have two arguments to make it slow again.

Comment: @Daniel: Found it, it is an optimization for the simple case. Line 511 @ https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs I'm guessing there are more optimizations than '%s' in production FSharp.Core.