# System.Console.WriteLine() vs printfn in F#

Tags: .net, f#

What is the difference between the following two statements in F#?
Are they any advantages or disadvantages compared to each other (excluding the obvious syntax differences)?

I understand that WriteLine() is part of .NET, but do not understand what implications this might have.

**The Sample Code:**

```
printfn "This is an integer: %d" 5
System.Console.WriteLine("This is an integer: {0}" , 5)
```

Comment: Mono uses System.IO.TextWriter https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fsi

Comment: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/

Comment: @MikeHarris what is your point? also, at least say whether you're talking about `printf` or `WriteLine`

Comment: @symbiont sorry I wrote that comment about 10 years ago and looking at it now I have not idea what my point was but I got 3 up votes so it must have make sense to a few people at the time. Looking at what I linked to I was talking about `printfn`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`printfn` and its various cousins have several advantages:

- They're **shorter**.
- They *can* do some **static type checking**; i.e. `printfn "%d" "bad type"` will not compile.
- ...but you don't have to do static type checking; `%O` prints any object
- They can print **"smart" representations** for things like arrays, tuples, and discriminated unions with `%A`
- They can be partially applied; i.e. `printfn "%d, %d" 3` is a valid expression.  This is particularly nifty since the compiler can check that you actually apply the right number of arguments when you later use this subexpression - unlike `Console.WriteLine` which will happily accept too many or too few parameters.

In practice, the most common partial application is likely to include just the format string; e.g.

```
let printParticle = printfn "Particle at (%d, %d), state %A, p = %f"

printParticle 2 3 //compile time warning about ignored value
printParticle 3 4 someState 0.4 //fine
printParticle 5 6 someState 0.4 0.7 //compile-time error
```

However, prior to F# 3.1, it's also **slow**.  It's plenty fast enough to keep up with you the coder, but if you're using it in some form of serialization, it could turn into a bottleneck.  The [F# 3.1 release announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) (which is distributed as part of Visual Studio 2013) claims to improve the performance dramatically, though I have not verified this.

Personally, I usually use printfn for exploratory coding, and then I largely stick to `%A` with the occasional other specifier thrown in.  However, the .NET native string formatting is still useful in some cases for its detailed culture and formatting-related options.  If you want maximum speed direct concatenation (or a `StringBuilder`) will easily outperform both as this avoids interpreting the format string.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear and useful answer. If you could elaborate on the "partially applied" part, that'd be even better!

Comment: I agree that `printfn` and related functions should generally be used instead of `Console.WriteLine()`, but it's worth mentioning that they're also relatively slow (which may matter for some use cases).

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the update - I guess I never tried to use it for huge amounts of data :-)  updated!

Comment: @JackP. F# 3.1 apparently optimizes printfn better - the release page advertises an example where performance is up to 40x better (presumably due to runtime reflection being avoided).  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Here are some pros and cons of `printf`-like functions compared to `Console.WriteLine`.

Pros:

- `printfn` functions are type-safe:

  ```
  printfn "This is an integer: %i" 5 // works
  printfn "This is an integer: %i" "5" // doesn't compile
  ```
- It's easy to do partial application with `printfn`, which is not the case with `Console.WriteLine` due to excessive number of overloads:

  ```
  [1; 2; 3] |> List.iter (printfn "%i; ")
  ```
- `printfn` support F# types better via `%A` specifier.

Cons:

Aside from not being able to reuse parameters as @mydogisbox mentioned, [`printfn`-like functions are much slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248787/why-is-printf-in-f-so-slow)  than `Console.WriteLine` (due to using reflection); you shouldn't use the former for logging purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from style, `System.Console.WriteLine` has the advantage of being able to reuse parameters, i.e. `System.Console.WriteLine("This is a integer twice: {0} {0}", 5)`

Also, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519458/f-how-to-print-full-list-console-writeline-prints-only-first-three-elements/2519518#2519518), you can do pretty printing of F# object using `printfn` which you can't do with `System.Console.WriteLine` and since it doesn't take a tuple, you can do partial application with it.

As noted by others, `printfn` uses reflection and thus is significantly slower than `PrintLine`, but also is typesafe.

Answer (score 4):

The printfn function can be partially applicated.

```
let printDouble = printfn "%f"
printDouble 2.0
```

As the standard .NET functions take tuples as parameters in F#, you can't use partial application there.

A second advantage of printfn is, that the arguments are typed. So this won't compile:

```
let printDouble = printfn "%d"
printDouble 2.0
```